# string PNG conversion Returns Blurry Image

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, download, blurry

I'm making a website for makecode arcade [here](https://yu-hayate.github.io/Makecode-Yu-Hayate-Dithering/) and I'm making a string to PNG function called ConvertAndDownload
but when I download the image, its all blurry
for example
lets say that i have the string
img`1 2 3 4 5  6 7 8 9 a  b c d e f  1 3 7 a f`
it returns this but its suppose to me pixelated and not all blended together (image is 5x4 pixels)
[Converted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEEY3.png) (idk how to resize the image so this is what you get sry)

i tried to add `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;` but that didnt work,

heres the download image function

```
function convertAndDownload() {
    var makeCodeString = document.getElementById('makeCodeInput').value;
    var canvasData = convertImgStringToCanvas(makeCodeString, colors)
    var canvas = canvasData;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');   
    
    
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.href = dataURL;
    downloadLink.download = document.getElementById('varName').value + '.png';
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

Comment: What makes you think your resulting image is blurry? Viewing your image https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEEY3.png inside Photoshop at a magnifying level of 1600 it's all individual pixels - crisp and clean. What are you using to view the image? Irfanview for example smoothens the image if zoomed in - making it look blurry even if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the blurriness in your downloaded image, you need to ensure that your canvas size matches the size of your image. Additionally, you can disable image smoothing to prevent any interpolation that might cause blurriness. Here's how you can modify your convertAndDownload function:

```js
function convertAndDownload() {
    var makeCodeString = document.getElementById('makeCodeInput').value;
    var canvasData = convertImgStringToCanvas(makeCodeString, colors);
    var canvas = canvasData.canvas;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Set canvas size to match image size
    canvas.width = canvasData.width;
    canvas.height = canvasData.height;

    // Disable image smoothing
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.href = dataURL;
    downloadLink.download = document.getElementById('varName').value + '.png';
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simplified, but can be a good starter towards your image pixel scaling feature which you probably tried implement on your website. I tested it o your latest code availalbe under provided link. [image]

```js
convertImgStringToCanvas = (imgString) => {
imgString = imgString.replace('`', '').replace('img', '');
  const rows = imgString.trim().split(/\s{2,}/).map(row => row.trim());
  const width = rows[0].split(' ').length;
  const height = rows.length;

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // Set canvas size based on desired square size (could be adjusted to not use 1 to 1 ratio)
  const squareSize = 1;
  canvas.width = width * squareSize;
  canvas.height = height * squareSize;

  for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    const rowData = rows[y].split(' ');
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      const data = rowData[x];
      if (data !== '.') {
        const colorIndex = parseInt(data, 16) - 1;
        const color = colors[colorIndex];
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(x * squareSize, y * squareSize, squareSize, squareSize);
      } else {
        ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
        ctx.fillRect(x * squareSize, y * squareSize, squareSize, squareSize);
      }
    }
  }
    return canvas;
}
```

Comment: that does not work, the output of `convertImgStringToCanvas()` Is a canvas element

Comment: it works, the canvas is the output, and I have tested that on your website